# Building a Java Code for Grading Courses

Tags: java

I'm needing a bit of help getting started with a code for my Java course (I had to miss this week and am rather helpless without what they learned) and would appreciate any input on what I'm doing. My goal is to create a code that calculates grades based on inputs.

Here's what the final should look like running:

> Please enter the number of courses that you would like to calculate the Average Score, the Minimum Score and the Maximum Score:  2
>
> Please enter the name of the course: CSC 201
> Please enter a score for CSC 201 or type -1 to indicate that there is no more score for this course:
> *input various values here*
>
> The course name: CSC 201
> Number of scores: 2
> The average score: 80.0
> The minimum score: 70
> The maximum score: 90

I'm just... Not quite sure where to go. My base code's below, I just have no idea where to go beyond this, or even how to use Math.min and Math.max. Thanks for any help you can offer for ideas on how to go from here!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of courses that you would like to ");
        System.out.println("calculate the Average Score, the Minimum Score, and the Maximum Score: ");
        int status = input.nextInt();
        
        // I am stuck here...
        // 
        // > Math.min()
        // > Math.max()
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have a function and do not know what it does, look for its javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int)

Answer (score 3):

Let us list what you need to solve this problem:

- An **entry point** for your program, i.e., your `main` method. This is where execution starts
- Something to **read values** from a user. You already provided a `Scanner` with the underlying standard input stream (`System.in`). You just need to figure out how to use the `Scanner`: Basically, what you need is a method to receive integer values (`nextInt`) and a method that returns string values (e.g., `readLine`) Always look at the type signatures, and if you are unsure what the method does, read the Javadoc.
- A way to **output text** to the user. In your case, you can use `System.out.println`.
- **Control flow** structures: You want to repeatedly ask the user for an integer input, until -1 is entered. You can achieve this by using a `while`-loop.
- **Arithmetic operations** on integers, i.e., you want to **add** integers (which you can do using the `+` operator)
- **Arithmetic comparison** on integers, i.e., you want to compute the minimum, and the maximum among multiple integers

There was also a very similar question not too long ago. Look it up if you get stuck, but try to solve the exercise on your own first: [how to calculate min, max, sum, and avg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047555/how-to-calculate-min-max-sum-and-avg)